# Efficient way to match a point against regions

Tags: mongodb, geospatial, postgis

I have a list of circular regions identified by the centre (latitude, longitude) and a radius. And I have a list of points on the earth identified by their latitude and longitude. For each point, I want to find the regions that it comes under. Please note, both lists can run into millions.

What is the most efficient way of doing this?

Regards!

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB has built in support for bounds queries, so you can look for points within a given shape.  Circles (center + radius) are one of the supported types.  So, assuming you have a geospatial index defined on a location field (`db.places.ensureIndex( { loc : "2d" } )`or similar), you can do something like this:

```
> center = [50, 50]
> radius = 10
> db.places.find({"loc" : {"$within" : {"$center" : [center, radius]}}})
```

More info to be found here:

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Geospatial+Indexing#GeospatialIndexing-BoundsQueries

Comment: Thanks Adam. A follow-up question, if you don't mind - Does MongoDB perform well considering there are a million circular regions and there will be a new 'within' query for each location? Is there a way to optimize it - apart from the geo-spatial index?

Comment: Hard to say without actually running it.  The indexed geohashing does perform well, I can say that.  The $within operator I am less familiar with in terms of performance.  If you can keep your data set in RAM, and if this doesn't end up being CPU bound then I can't see why it wouldn't be fast.  Only one way to be sure though: test, test, test.... :)

Comment: If you need help with the index/query set up, or just want to post results and get feedback then just head on over to the mongodb-user Google group - we're a pretty responsive bunch :)